# Inconsistency and order of execution with async setState() in input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Consider TextInput in react-native, below implementation seems to be a standard approach:

```
<TextInput
  value={this.state.text}
  onChangeText={text => this.setState({ text })}
/>
```

However, setState() is an async function. I am wondering whether it is possible to encounter inconsistency due to the execution order of setState().

For example:

1. Type 'ab'
2. setState({ text: 'ab' })
3. setState({ text: 'a' })
4. this.state.text results in 'a'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> setState() is an async function. Whether it is possible to encounter inconsistency due to the execution order of setState()

Async `setState()` does not mean that `setState` will be called in any random order. `setState` is async means it will just update the state asynchronously.

In your case whenever some key is pressed `onChange` handler will be called and that will call `setState` which means `setState` will be called sequentially on every key press and will update the state in same sequence **but asynchronously**.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<TextInput
   onChange={(e) => this.setState({ text : e.target.value })}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are modifying the same state via different entry points, Example: Multiple parallel api calls, that's when there might be unexpected data due to race condition. To avoid this, you can use the callback approach i.e.

```
setState((prevState) => {return newState})
```